# Removing column while reading large TSV

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a .tsv file but keep getting this error:

> Warning: 3 parsing failures. row              col         expected
> actual                        529   SxSxOth     delimiter or quote
> 529    SxSxOth     closing quote at end of file                 529    NA
> 736 columns                     156 columns
>
> Warning message: Missing column names filled in: 'X736' [736]

ETA: The problem is that the file stops loading after row 529 when it should be loading 559 rows. The row in question looks fine to me. I tried deleting it from the source file and loading the file again but it switched the warning to row 528 and stopped loading the file after that.

Edit2: After further exploration, it turns out that the column "SxSxOth" is what's causing the problem. Is there a way to remove it while reading the TSV? There are 735 columns and I don't know the column number of "SxSxOth". The data types of the 735 columns are not the same - some are integer, some double, some character, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you want help with?  These are *warnings*, not *errors* (the two are distinct in R) so they won't necessarily get in the way of your analysis.  It is a good idea to check them out though. `read_tsv` is trying to tell you there's something weird about line 529 in your file.  Have you looked at it ... ???

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response. The problem is that the file stops loading after row 529 when it should be loading 559 rows. The row in question looks fine to me. I tried deleting it from the source file and loading the file again but it switched the warning to row 528 and stopped loading the file after that.

Comment: This is going to be very hard to debug unless we can see the actual file.  What happens if you delete, say, rows 1-500? Does it break on line 29 of the new file?

Comment: I appreciate the difficulty in debugging this without seeing the actual file but I am unfortunately bound by HIPAA that prevents me from sharing it.

Comment: @Epi2020 Did you read Ben's comment to completion?

Comment: Upon further investigation, it looks like the column "SxSxOth" is the cause of the problems, not so much the rows. Is there a way I could exclude this column from loading the TSV? There are 735 columns in all and I don't know the column number of this particular one.

Comment: see the `col_types` arg in `?read_tsv`.  There isn't a `skip_columns` argument, but if you use a character code of `_` in `col_types` for the unwanted column it will be skipped ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568409/override-column-types-when-importing-data-using-readrread-csv-when-there-are) provides an applicable answer:

### generate example file

```
writeLines("a\tb\tc\nd\te\tf", con="tmpfile.dat")
```

### regular reading

```
read_tsv("tmpfile.dat", col_names=FALSE)
```

I've used `col_names=FALSE` here because I'm lazy and didn't include anything like col names in my example ...

### reading skipping one specified column

"X2" is skipped (this is an automatically generated name since I used `col_names=FALSE`), all others use the default parsing/guessing rules.

```
read_tsv("tmpfile.dat", col_names=FALSE, col_types=cols(.default="?", X2="_"))
```

In  your example you would use `SxSxOth="_"`

(based on a comment by @mkirzon under @Nick's answer)

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the same warning and truncated result as before:

`read_tsv("file.tsv", col_types = cols(.default="?", SxSxOth = "_")) `

I skipped `col_names=FALSE` since my TSV did have column names.