# How to specify column types with abbreviations when skipping columns with read_csv

Tags: r, readr

I would like to read in selected columns from a CSV file, using abbreviations supported by the `cols` function in the `readr` package. However, when I skip columns, `readr` tries to guess the column type, rather than using my specification, unless I specify the columns by name or set a default.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

out <- tibble(a = c(1234, 5678),
       b = c(9876, 5432),
       c = c(4321, 8901))

write_csv(out, "test.csv")

test <- read_csv("test.csv",
                 col_select = c(a, c),
                 col_types = "cc")

typeof(test$c)
#> [1] "double"
```

I can get the correct specification by explicitly indicating the column name:

```
test2 <- read_csv("test.csv",
                 col_select = c(a, c),
                 col_types = c(a = "c", c = "c"))
typeof(test2$c)
#> [1] "character"
```

I can also get the correct specification by setting character as the default, as suggested in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568409/override-column-types-when-importing-data-using-readrread-csv-when-there-are). But I'm wondering if there is a way to get the correct specification using the abbreviation "cc" or -- alternatively -- how to generate an abbreviation string based on the columns that were skipped. My real use case involves a large number of skipped columns, so I don't want to use `-` or `_` to specify the skipped columns.

Comment: The answer to the question " if there is a way to get the correct specification using the abbreviation (i.e., "cc")" is yes, and it is to use `-` or `_`. Maybe what you need to figure out is how to generate an abbreviation string based on the columns that were skipped.

Comment: @neilfws Good point -- I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I've rewritten what I wrote earlier to be more clear based on an assumed understanding of what you are asking.

If you want to get the col_types for the columns in your csv file prior to any skipping or manual changes then the easiest thing to do is to use the `spec_csv()` argument of your file which generate a col class text that will show you how `read_csv()` will classify each column type.

From there you can copy, paste and edit that into your `col_types` argument to only bring in the columns & column types that you want. That can be done using the `cols_only()` argument instead of `cols()`.

```
spec_csv("test.csv")
```

This will automatically generate in your output console:

```
cols(
  a = col_double(),
  b = col_double(),
  c = col_double()
)
```

The output will tell you what the default reader column types would be (PS you can manipulate the `spec_csv()` argument just like the `read_csv` argument to increase the guess size eg.`guess_max`  for the column types.

```
#manually copied and pasted the above output, changed the default to the desired type and deleted the columns I didn't want

read_csv("test.csv",
         col_types=cols_only(a = col_character(),
                             c = col_character())
  )
```

I used the long form (col_character) but you can instead you the abbreviation as you already indicated earlier.

Please let me know if this is what you were asking or if there is any clarity that I can provide.

Comment: hey! I retyped it to make it more clear, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for `col_types` in `?read_csv`. You can use `_` or `-` to specify a skipped column:

```
read_csv("test.csv",
         col_select = c(a, c),
         col_types = "c-c")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  a     c    
  <chr> <chr>
1 1234  4321 
2 5678  8901
```

Comment: Thanks -- my real use case involves a lot of columns, so using `_` or `-` is not an option. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Some more realistic example data would help in that case.